# How to get value of spesific element in list with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have a table like that. i want to get spesific classes' value. For examle, i want only value of "model" and "year" classes.

```
<table id="list_tbody">
  <tr>
    <th class="model">Ford</th>
    <th class="year">2000</th>
    <th class="colour">red</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th class="model">Toyota</th>
    <th class="year">2020</th>
    <th class="colour">blue</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="model">Audi</th>
    <th class="year">2018</th>
    <th class="colour">black</th>
  </tr>
  .
  .
  .
  </table>
```

To get all tr i use;

```
cars=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="list_tbody"]/tr')
```

So all my tr elements are in my "cars" list. To get each of them i use for loop

```
for car in cars: ...
```

i use something like that but it does not working.

```
for car in cars:
  carModel= car.find_element_by_xpath('//th[@class="model"]').text
  carYear= car.find_element_by_xpath('//th[@class="year"]').text
  print(f"Model : {carModel}, Year : {carYear}")
```

i want to see that:

```
Model : Ford  - Year : 2020
Model : Toyota - Year : 2010
           .              .
           .              .
           .              .
```

But it is always returnig only first item of list. So how can i get spesific part of element in elements list? I also tried to get value with beautifulsoup after getting elements list with selenium. But this time when i type

```
...
Carmodel=car.find("th" class_="model").text
```

it says "   'WebElement' object has no attribute 'find'   "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the correct solution, just missing a `.` inside the `xpath`s.
So try this:

```
for car in cars:
  carModel= car.find_element_by_xpath('.//th[@class="model"]').text
  carYear= car.find_element_by_xpath('.//th[@class="year"]').text
  print(f"Model : {carModel}, Year : {carYear}")
```

Without the `.` there your `xpath` searches related to entire page, not inside that element `car`. To say Selenium to search 'from here' `.` is used.

That's the `xpath` syntax to say 'here'. Like `//` saying 'anywhere' and `@` is for 'attribute' `.` comes to say 'from here' to build relative expression relative to the given node.

Comment: Please open a new, separated question otherwise moderators will close it since each question here should ask 1 specific question. I will try to help you there, but I'm going to have meetings at work in the nearest time, so I can't promise I will be able. Also, if some answer resolved your problem it's a good manner to accept that answer. This means the question received the answer. Also this will give 2 points to you and 15 to the person answered.

Answer (score 0):

you can store all th element for model name and year. Check out the below code :

**Code :**

```
model_name_list = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "th.model")
for model_name in model_name_list:
   print(model_name.text)
```